# Is there a runoff in the Chicago Mayoral elections when one candidate gets a majority in the first round?

Tags: united-states, election, local-government

In the recent mayoral election there were 15 or so candidates,
with the top 2 going to a runoff. What would have happened if one candidate had received a majority of 51% of the vote in that election, would they still have had a runoff?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about the Chicago mayoral elections, the answer is **No**. A runoff would only be held if no candidate received a majority in the first round.

The [Chicago Board of Election Commissioners, "2019 Election Information Pamphlet & Calendar," April 10, 2018](https://app.chicagoelections.com/documents/general/M2019-Election-Calendar-Eng.pdf) states on page 3 that:

> The candidate receiving a majority of the votes cast for each office
>   shall be declared elected.
>   **If no candidate receives a majority of the votes, a runoff election shall be held**
>   on April 2, 2019, when only the names of the candidates receiving the
>   highest and second highest number of votes at the February 26, 2019
>   election shall appear on the ballot. [65 ILCS 20/21-5, 20/21-12; 10
>   ILCS 5/2A-1.1(b) and 5/2A-1.2(d)]

---

This isn't a universal rule. In Washington State, for example, the first round is a non-partisan ["top-two"](https://ballotpedia.org/Top-two_primary) primary and the top 2 candidates advance to the general election even if one gets a majority.

[Washington State Elections FAQ:](https://www.sos.wa.gov/elections/faqcandidates.aspx)

> The two candidates who receive the most votes in the Primary Election qualify for the General Election. Candidates must also receive at least 1% of the votes cast in that race to advance to the General Election